# Agregar componentes de react a las diferentes apps de Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django

he visto varios en Youtube de cómo integrar react con Django, la mayoría lo hace con Django rest framework, no he visto algún vídeo que no lo haga con DRF.

mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo integrar react o componentes de react a las diferentes aplicaciones de django sin DRF?, ¿Es posible agregar componentes de react a cada app por separado?